# S3 connection to application

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I wrote an app that displays images by ID and all the images save and located in S3.
I have 2 instances and 1 LB in my AWS machine and the index.js is located in both instances.
In my index.js I wrote the path to my S3 bucket and I get an error message like this :

> Blockquote
>   This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

The code in index.js :

```
//Get Images Names by Id / Color from MongoDB

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://db_usr:db_pass@ds023550.mlab.com:23550/db_ringapp2016_g');
var userSchema = require('./1_define_schema');
var size = 0;
var express = require('express'),
    url = require('url'),
    app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var Upload = require('s3-uploader');
var restify = require('restify');

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

// connection error
mongoose.connection.once('error', function (err) {
    console.log('connectiob error' + err);
});

//connecting to DB
mongoose.connection.once('open', function () {
    console.log("============================");
    console.log("Connected Successfully to DB");
    console.log("============================");

    userSchema.find({}, function(err, user){
        if(err) throw err;
        //first route - call first get function from WS.
        app.get('/AllPictures' , 

            function (req, res) {
                console.log("DB: Get all Pictures");
                res.status(200).json(user[0].Name);
        });
    })

    //second route - call second function from WS (by Id).
    app.get('/PicById/:Id/:Size', function (req, res) { 
        userSchema.find({Id:req.params.Id} , function(err, user){
            if(err) throw err;
                console.log("DB: Get Pic by ID: "+req.params.Id+" from MongoDB");
                console.log("Name Pic: "+user[0].Name);
                console.log("Size Pic: "+req.params.Size);
                var temp = user[0].Name.split(".");
                var result = temp[0]+req.params.Size+"."+temp[1];
                console.log(result);
                res.send('<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head></head><body><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/galshaharbucket/'+result+'"></body></html>');
                console.log("============================");
            })
    })

    //thired route - call thired get from WS (by Color).
    app.get('/PicByColor/:Color', function (req, res) { 
        userSchema.find({Color:req.params.Color}, function(err, user){
            if(err) throw err;
            var names = [];
                console.log("DB: Get Pic by Color: "+req.params.Color+" from MongoDB"); 
                console.log("--------------------");
                for(var i = 0; i<user.length; ++i){
                    var temp = user[i].Name.split(".");
                    names [i] = temp[0]+"S."+temp[1];
                    console.log("Name Pic: "+names [i]);
                    console.log("--------------------");
                }
                var temp = [];
                for(var i = 0; i<user.length; ++i){
                    temp [i] = '<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/galshaharbucket/'+names [i]+'">'
                }
                var result = temp.join("");
                res.send('<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head></head><body>'+result+'</body></html>');
                console.log("============================");
            })
    })

    app.get('/GetAllPictures', function (req, res) { 
        userSchema.find({}, function(err, user){
            if(err) throw err;
            var names = [];
                console.log("DB: Get All Pictures from MongoDB");   
                for(var i = 0; i<user.length; ++i){
                    var temp = user[i].Name.split(".");
                    names [i] = temp[0]+"S."+temp[1];
                }
                var temp = [];
                for(var i = 0; i<user.length; ++i){
                    temp [i] = '<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/galshaharbucket/'+names [i]+'">'
                }
                var result = temp.join("");
                res.send('<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head></head><body>'+result+'</body></html>');
                console.log("============================");
            })
    })

    // Upload an image
    app.get('/Upload/:Path', function (req, res) { 
        var knox = require('knox').createClient({
            key: 'AKIAJ4ROKKJBECGFSYIA'
          , secret: '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'
          , bucket: 'galshaharbucket'
        });

        var file = req.params.Path;
            console.log(file);
            var upload_name = "upload_"+ file; // or whatever you want it to be called

            knox.putFile(file, upload_name, {
                 "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
             }, function (err, result) {
                 if (err != null) {
                     return console.log(err);
                 } else {
                     console.log("Uploaded to amazon S3");
                     console.log("--------------------");
                 }
             });
    })


});


// The function that recieve the name from mongo and display it

function getImageById(){
    Input = document.getElementById("imageId");
    Size = document.getElementById("imageSize");
    size=Size.value;
    alert(size);

    if(Input.value==""){
        alert("Please Enter Id Number Between 1-33");
        return;
    }

        url = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/galshaharbucket/PicById/"+Input.value+"/"+Size.value;
        //url = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/galshaharbucket/'+name;

        if(Size.value=="L"){
            popupWindow = window.open(
            url,'popUpWindow','height=658,width=1120,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
        }

        if(Size.value=="M"){
            popupWindow = window.open(
            url,'popUpWindow','height=525,width=820,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
        }

        if(Size.value=="S"){
            popupWindow = window.open(
            url,'popUpWindow','height=330,width=520,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
        }
}


function getImageByColor(str){
    Input = document.getElementById("imageColor");

    if(Input.value==""){
        alert("Please Enter a Color: red / green / blue / yellow");
        return;
    }
    else{
        path = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/galshaharbucket/PicByColor/"+Input.value;
        popupWindow = window.open(
        path,'popUpWindow','height=608,width=1020,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
    }
}

function uploadImage(){
        var fileChooser = document.getElementById('path');
        var results = document.getElementById('results');
        var file = fileChooser.files[0];
        alert(file.name);
        path = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/galshaharbucket/Upload/"+file.name+"";
        popupWindow = window.open(
        path,'popUpWindow','height=608,width=1020,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}

function getAllPics(){
        path = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/galshaharbucket/GetAllPictures";
        popupWindow = window.open(
        path,'popUpWindow','height=608,width=1020,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')

}
```

How I can display the image correctly without an error ? What can cause to this error ?

[image]

Thank you,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your bucket policy and make sure to have something like (or use AWS policy generator under the Bucket Permission section).

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::galshaharbucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

if `galshaharbucket` is your bucket name so it grants everyone access to the objects in the specified folder.

you can read [more about bucket policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-iam-policies.html)